# Название Tab вкладок в ActionBar

Tags: actionbar, android

У меня имеется ActionBar в нем название Tab вкладок задано напрямую(Вкладка1,Вкладка2,Вкладка3). Подскажите как задать название вкладок через String переменные из res/values/strings.xml ? Это мне нужно для локализации приложения.

```
public class Bormio extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapterTabsBormio mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Tab Titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Вкладка1", "Вкладка2", "Вкладка3" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bormio);

        // Initialize

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new PagerAdapterTabsBormio(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Исправил - теперь такой код

```
    private ViewPager viewPager;
private PagerAdapterTabsArabba mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private Resources res = getResources();
// Tab Titles
private String[] tabs =  {res.getString(R.string.list1), res.getString(R.string.list2), res.getString(R.string.list3) };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.arabba);

    // Initialize

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new PagerAdapterTabsArabba(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Comment: Я столкнулся с проблемой в своем проекте, у меня все работает, кроме одного - на табах нет надписей. Можете кинуть, как вы вставляли надписи за массива tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] tabs = { res.getString(R.string.x1), res.getString(R.string.x2), res.getString(R.string.x3)};
```

Comment: 04-26 21:22:33.063: E/AndroidRuntime(17167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-26 21:22:33.063: E/AndroidRuntime(17167):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @qwen дебажте, смотрите в какой строке и почему может валиться NullPointerException

Comment: @qwen 

Resources res = getResources();
String[] tabs =  {res.getString(R.string.slopes), res.getString(R.string.map), res.getString(R.string.info)};

в onCreate перенесите

Comment: Спасибо !!! Все получилось!!!

Comment: @qwen,

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);//Добавить
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);